# `UIAlertView` appears multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I display an alert view in the `didConnect` method for bluetooth. For some reason, it fires four times. I'm trying to bandaid it and it is not working too well. Basically, I put the alert view in a method of its own, and call that method in `didConnect`. That's when it fires four times. I'm trying to set it up to only fire once. What I tried to do was set the alert views method to return a `TRUE` value. Then I do this:

```
if ([successfulConnection self] == FALSE) {
        [self successfullConnection];

    }
```

This works great the first time, but then the method is set to `TRUE` for the remainder of the time. I have the feeling that if I set it back to equal `FALSE` at the end of the if statement, then it will fire four times and I'll be right back where I started. Does anyone know how to change the above code to have it only fire once when it tries to fire four times?

Also tried replacing the above code with this in my `didConnect`, but it never fired at all:

```
[successfulConnection self];

if (successfulConnection.visible == YES) {
[successfulConnection dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can set your boolean to FALSE when any alert view button is pressed. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: One common way to handle this is to have an ivar like "didFinish". Its initialized to NO, and once you create and show an alert, you set it to TRUE, and from then on if you get repeating messages, you know you already got return message.

Comment: Alert views have a property called visible. Just check whether that returns YES, and if so, don't present another one.

Comment: @rdelmar I just tried that, didn't seem to even display at all but that was very helpful. I just updated the bottom of my question with the code I tried.

Comment: @rdelmar How would I get it to not display another one? I tried `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex`, but that didn't work. Either way, I think your answer is really close to solving it.

Comment: Is successfulConnection a property for your alert view? What is [successfulConnection self] supposed to be doing?

Comment: @rdelmar `[successfulConnection self]` is what displays the `UIAlertView`, I put it in its own method.

Comment: You sure that's not show rather than self? Self makes no sense there.

Comment: @rdelmar I created a method called successfulConnection, and the only thing in that method is the alert view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31270/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-oral-b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call successfulConnection from your didConnect method, I think this should work (myAlert is the property name for the alert view):

```
-(void)successfulConnection {
    if (! self.myAlert) {
        self.myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ttile" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [self.myAlert show];
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    self.myAlert = nil;
    //do whatever with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to just have a boolean that gets set to true when the UIAlertView is displayed, and then false when the UIAlertView is dismissed. Then, whenever you are going to show the UIAlertView, first check if it is already displaying.

Comment: I'm unsure of exactly how to do that. I placed `successfulConnection = TRUE;` at the end of the if statement and it fired four times again.

Answer (score 0):

## These are methods you can use according to your requirement:

#### EDIT : Perfect way... if you dont want to upload your app on App Store

To know that `alertView` is `currently` `visible` `or not`.

`Usage` : Display alertView only if necesary other its already present.

```
-(UIAlertView *)getLastAlertView
{
  Class UIAlertManager = objc_getClass("_UIAlertManager");
  UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
  return topMostAlert;
}
```

---

`Dissmiss` `any` `alertView` `present` which you don't know.

`Usage` : dissmiss all alertView and then present new one

```
-(void)dissmissLastAlert
{
  Class UIAlertManager = objc_getClass("_UIAlertManager");
  UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
  if (topMostAlert) {
    [topMostAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
  }
}
```